# CALDAV protocol

Tags: java, web-services, report, webdav, caldav

sorry for my english but I'm french. I will do my best.

I have to write a WEB SERVICE ( in java with JAX-RS ) to transform my data to icalendar format. This part is ok.

Now I'm learning the caldav protocol to use my web service with mozilla Thunderbird. But I not able to find any doc on how the exchange is ?

What request is sent from thunderbird to retreive the calendar ? My webservice should be able to catch all of the type ( REPORT - MOVE - COPY - PUT - POST - ....) ?

I need some explication or a good documentation of how caldav works.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In theory, [RFC 4791](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4791.html) should contain all you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I understand the pop3 part - If I was explaining IMAP4 to someone then rather than pointing to the RFC I would say:

telnet imap.example.org 143
 A login username password
 B list "" * 
 C logout

These are the raw commands that I use to test IMAP4; What are the ones for CalDAV?
 Something like https://github.com/alexxroche/AIF/blob/master/ISP/servers/POP3

**update**

ok, I think I've got this:

To read/list an entry

```
curl -X GET --user admin:pass-phrase --output test.ics "https://api.example.com/calDAV/calNAME"
```

To add an entry:

```
curl --basic --request PUT \\
--header "Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8" \\
--user admin:pass-phrase --data-binary @out.ics
```

(I've tried to use a few of the cURL flags/arguments as demonstration. You can even send data as a string with

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.url/calDAV/calNAME" \\
-F "data-binary=really-long-string" \\
-F "user=admin:pass-phrase" \\
-F "the other data=can be added like this"
```

Comment: If you don't have cURL then wget of lynx/links or even perl::LWP would work. The point is that you just need to be able to craft and send a more-complex-than-you-usually-type-into-a-browser http request, (though obviously we should be using https where possible.)